# Для чего нужны "+" с двух сторон и кавычки? color = 'hsl(' + hue + ', ' + saturation + '%, ' + lightness + '%)';

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу разобраться в приведении. Нужно было менять hsl, но когда узнал, что нужно писать вот так `color = 'hsl(' + hue + ', ' + saturation + '%, ' + lightness + '%)';`, то не понял зачем тут везде по два знака "+", и кавычки. Вот пример части кода:

```
if (players[i] === 'Вы') {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
} else {
  var hue = '240';
  var saturation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var lightness = '50';
  var color = 'hsl(' + hue + ', ' + saturation + '%, ' + lightness + '%)';
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
}
```

Может кто то дать ссылку на статью или рассказать почему нужно писать именно так? Только начинаю знакомство с js

Comment: Почитайте про базовые понятия в js, хотя конкатенация строк используется наверно во всех ЯП. https://learn.javascript.ru/operators

Comment: `var a = 1 + 2 + 3;` - зачем два знака "+" вокруг двойки?

Comment: Только я не понимаю откуда берутся эти "1" и "3" в варианте выше. Я думал, что если оставлю просто hue, то всё будет работать так же т.к. перед hue скобка, а после запятая. Но почему то добавляются кавычки и плюсы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var hue = '240';
var saturation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var lightness = '50';
var color = `hsl(${hue}, ${saturation}%, ${lightness}%)`;
console.log(color);
```